# How to put a file (.jks, .p12) as variable?

Tags: apk, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm working on a gitlab-ci pipeline to automate build, sign "apk" and deploy to the play store.
The pipeline work fine but the two files ".jks" to sign the "apk" and the ".p12" for my Google cloud platform service are now in my repository and it's not a secure way to do it. What I want to do is to put this two files ".jks and .p12" as a gitlab-ci variable to avoid putting this files in my repo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could define gitlab ci variable of file type

here is the doc for gitlab ce :

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-file-type-cicd-variables

In the settings of your project, you will need to define a variable (file type).

Then gitlab will create a temporary file for this variable with your file content.

You could use it directly
or use `cp` command like this:

```
cp $MY_SECRET_FILE $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
```

edit:
binary files seems not supported, so follow and upvote following issue : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/205379

Comment: Thank you for your answer . the problem is that i can't have the files (jks or .p12) content as text or json to put it in the variable type "file" .. what i want is that when i chose type variable "file" in gitlab-ci it will show me an upload button to upload my file .. so i need to convert my files into text to get the content ... it's insane ....

Comment: thank you ! i juste replace .p12 file with json file so i can get the content and convert .jks to base64 also .

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab ci/cd now supports binary files please check
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files